# Sql Server Express edition - Could not allocate space for object [Table] in database [DB] because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, database-size

I have reached the Sql Server Express edition limit of 10 Go of space per database and for every new INSERT I have this error :

```
2020-08-10 14:21:58.75 spid67 Could not allocate space for object [Table] in database [DB] 
because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. 
Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, 
adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

2020-08-10 14:21:58.75 spid67 CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed 
because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database.
```

To be sure I checked the remaining space with this query :

```
SELECT 
  database_name = DB_NAME(database_id)
, log_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'LOG' THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
, row_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'ROWS' THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
, total_size_mb = CAST(SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
FROM sys.master_files WITH(NOWAIT)
WHERE database_id = DB_ID() 
GROUP BY database_id
```

Which give me :

```
database_name|log_size_mb|row_size_mb|total_size_mb|
-------------|-----------|-----------|-------------|
DB           |    1224.00|   10184.00|     11408.00|
```

The row_size is my main issue, indeed I have accumulated a lot of data over time in a single table (few millions rows) but **I only need to keep 1 year of these data**, which is approximately 1/3 of the rows. So I deleted the old rows with a `DELETE` statement and I later read that it does not free the space instantly. And by running the query above the row_size effectively stays the same. I read a lot about database and file shrinking but it does not seems to be a good idea if the table number of rows will grow again fast which is my case.

My question is : is there a way to quickly fix my error by freeing space and allow my database to be able to insert new rows ? **My need is to allow again new inserts in this database after deleting records of my huge table**.

Note: I don't want to switch to another server with more space or to the standard edition. Because the express edition is sufficient for my use case, the table will grow fast again but I want to limit that situation happening again later.

EDIT: my table doesn't seems to be a heap because it contains in sys.partitions one index of type "Clustered Index/b-tree".

Comment: Run [DBCC UPDATEUSAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-updateusage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as a first step

Comment: @DenisRubashkin thanks for the insight, though after running `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE ([DB_NAME],[MY_LARGE_TABLE]);` I still have the error on the insert and row_size_mb stay the same, did I miss something ?

Comment: Seems the table is a heap. To deallocate empty data pages from the heap run `ALTER TABLE [MY_LARGE_TABLE] REBUILD;`. More info on the issue here: [DELETE Operation in SQL Server HEAPs](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/delete-operation-sql-server-heaps/)

Comment: Your query only show us the file size, not how full the file are. There's plenty of stuff out there for this, I use my own sp_dbinfo, sp_tableinfo and sp_indexinfo. Might be a starting point to dig into this database: https://karaszi.com/articlesandutilities

Comment: Isn't the REBUILD likely to fail because it copies the old data to a new set of pages and those won't be available because we already reach the size limit? It is of course worth a try. If it is a B-tree that uses lots of space, then REORGANIZE would be sort of in-place. Otherwise, perhaps a shrink is needed after all, to do a type of compaction "in place". And then sort out the situation (probably create a clustered index on the table(s)).

Comment: Yeah indeed ALTER TABLE ... REBUILD is trying to allocate a new page and the size limit is already reached so it fails : "Could not allocate a new page for database". I just checked my table is not a heap (edited my question accordingly). @TiborKaraszi after shrinking the database, why do you think I need to create a clustered index ?

Comment: Because heaps sucks.  Or, rather, SQL Server sucks at managing heaps. But since your table isn't a heap, then just to reorganize instead of rebuild! And no shrink.

Comment: Thanks @TiborKaraszi it fixed by insert issues! not sure how many time I have until it fil again but at least it situation is unblocked

Comment: check this answer too: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/273179/sql-server-2016-table-cant-grow-while-313-mb-is-still-available-in-the-databas/273181#273181

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "it fixed by insert issues". How did you fix it? Is the table a heap or a clustered table? Why did it hold on to the storage if the table is clustered (it shouldn't)? How will you make sure it doesn't happen again? Etc.